# How to use std:: getline correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, parsing, std, getline

I have a csv file and a header file that creates a struct that i want to parse the data of the csv into
and then some code to parse the data, basically each line of the csv has a value correlated with price. Most of the processing logic has been removed to focus on reading the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


 int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])
 {
    std::ifstream BTCUSD("short.csv", std::fstream::in); //open file with dat
    int i = 0;
    const INT32 lines = std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(BTCUSD),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n'); //the number of lines in file -
    // Do some stuff with `lines`.

    if (BTCUSD.is_open()) //error catching for opening file 
        {
        std::string currentline;
        char endofL = '\n';
        std::getline(BTCUSD, currentline, endofL); //ignore first line in file
        while (std::getline(BTCUSD, currentline, endofL)) {     //get each line
              // Parsing logic would go here.
              std::cout << "parsing line " << i << std::endl;
              std::cout << "current line: " << currentline << std::endl;
              i++;
         }

    std::cout << i << " lines parsed." << std::endl;
    BTCUSD.close();

}
else {
    std::cout << "Couldn't open file - no elements imported." << std::endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

At first I was using a dataset of 4 million lines and I thought that might be a problem but I shortened it to about 80 lines and I cant seem to go into the parsing section of my code.
So it loads and opens the file but then its like I cant get the getline to process lines.

By the way the file is a csv file that contains the following info structured the following way:
seconds since unix epoch(every 60 seconds), open price for that time interval, high price for that time interval, low price for that time interval, close price for that time interval, BTC transacted in that time interval, USD transacted in that time interval, volume weighted average for that price interval.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to describe, you should replace the body of your `while` loop with a comment, as in `while (std::getline(BTCUSD, currentline, endofL)) { /* do stuff */ }`. Any code that is not needed to reproduce the problem has no place in a [mre].

Comment: Once you remove the innards of the loop, it should be easier to strip things before the loop. Get rid of no-longer used variables, starting with `pos`, and ending with `lines`. Has the problem disappeared yet?

Comment: The [mre] is a powerful debugging tool. More often than not, the process of making the MRE is abandoned early when the reduced noise around the bug leads you to spotting and fixing the bug. If you can make a MRE and still not have a solution, either you're missing a bit of information, and that gets an answer on Stack Overflow within minutes, or you have a really good question or ran into something nasty that needs the assistance of a domain expert. Quite a few of those on Stack Overflow, but it might take a few hours or days before the right one drops in. They tend to be busy folks.

Comment: Ok so Im going to edit the code to a minimum reproducible example as I still get seem to get into the while loop.  I need the endofL because thats the end of line delimiter no?

Comment: Yea I figured, I mean I have been searching around for my answer since last night and just am so exhausted at the moment i feel like im out of solutions, I mean even now commenting out all the excess code, I think I'm still using getline wrong, but from the refences ive looked at im using it exactly as i should.

Comment: Wait I think I may have just found the solution ... while looking around I noticed somewhere that an end ofline character is /r/n on windows rather than just /n .... is that true?

Comment: Ok so im rebuilding my code and earlier this line didnt seem to be an issue but now it's causing me problems: const int lines = std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(BTCUSD), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n'); //the number of lines in file , so let's say I don't know the amount of lines in a file before hand is there no other way to determine that but by iterating through it beforehand?

Comment: OK I figured it out I had to reset my file stream back to the beginning after using const int lines = std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(BTCUSD), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n'); //the number of lines in file    to count the number of lines in my input file

Comment: This question is no longer useful to anyone (except possibly its author) because the code in the question no longer exhibits the problem described in the answer. VTC.

Comment: Yea sorry about that , I edited it back to include the problem and solution just in case someone stumbles across it.

Comment: *"let's say I don't know the amount of lines in a file before hand is there no other way to determine that but by iterating through it beforehand"* -- Another question you could ask is if there is an approach where you do not need to determine that beforehand. (See [`std::vector'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).)

Comment: OK this is helpful and can see where it may be a more elegant solution, basically a vector is almost kind of like a primitive linked list correct?  But if data is never added to, or removed or edited/manipulated for that matter,  isn't a static solution still fine? Like I said I can see the benefits and appreciate the response, I just want to be thorough and understand why I might choose the vector solution over the array if array works.  Besides resetting the input stream to the beginning, is there any benefit to using vector over an array if I never plan to change the size once initialized?

Answer (score 1):

So the root of the issue I was experiencing was I was using :

```
const int lines = std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(BTCUSD), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n'); //the number of lines in file
```

to count the number of lines in my file, and I didn't know that you had to reset the input stream with `BTCUSD.seekg(0);` after invoking this.
Thank you everyone who commented.

Comment: Yes, that invocation of `std::count` causes the rest of the file to be read, leaving the file in an "end-of-file" state.